# Can an IRA contribution be made on the same date of the tax deadline and still count for that tax submission?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, roth-ira, contribution

The deadline for taxes and IRA contributions for FY2018 in USA is April 15, 2019. If I haven't made a contribution yet for FY2018, can I go to a bank on Monday, April 15, 2019 and make a contribution that will count on my 2018 taxes?

Is there any time deadline on this, or can the contribution be made on that same day anytime the bank is open? For example, some banks close after 5pm which is normal business hours, so would a contribution made at 5:30pm on April 15th still count?

Answer (score 5):

My brick and mortar bank has a sign, “deposits made after 3pm will be credited on the next business day.”

I would make sure the bank gives you a receipt to show they are crediting for 2018 tax year. Call them if you plan to get there after 2pm or so, and confirm they can open the account for 2018.